# org.eclipse.rdf4j vs org.openrdf

Tags: sesame, rdf4j, openrdf

I am learning on RDF and framework to implement them from [RDF4J](http://docs.rdf4j.org/rdf-tutorial/#_using_rdf4j_to_create_rdf_models). While exploring I came across two APIs that seem to be very similar.

[This](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/1.0/org/eclipse/rdf4j/model/class-use/IRI.html) is the one that RDF4J uses in its examples. These start with *org.eclipse.rdf4j*....

There is a very similar API [here](http://archive.rdf4j.org/javadoc/sesame-4.1.0/org/openrdf/model/IRI.html), which starts with *org.openrdf*....

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 2):

Before becoming an eclipse project RDF4J was hosted at www.openrdf.org. Eclipse require all Java projects to use the org.eclipse package prefix and the packages were renamed.

Comment: Might be good to mention that when hosted at openrdf.org, the project was called "OpenRDF Sesame". Eclipse RDF4J is basically the successor of that project.